# Git Issue: is a merge but no -m option was given

Tags: git

I'm trying to undo a single git commit that is NOT a merge but I still get this error. However, the commit that I am trying to revert to is a merge but I do not want to undo that merge. I would like to keep the merge but undo the single commit after. What would the correct command to do so be?

My current code is

```
$ git revert <old_commit_hash>

...is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

Comment: Where did you get the hash from? The `revert` error indicates that the hash ID is the hash ID of a merge commit. You can view the log message of the commit itself, and see a combined diff of the merge, with `git show <hash>`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand u correctly. If not, give info pls.

You could try it with a interactive rebase and remove the commit

just

```
$ git rebase -i Head~n
```

N ist the number of last commits. Then delete “pick” from the commit and type d for delete.